# Animation by PNG frames

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation

I have several PNG images that if it will be presented one after the other they will create a short animation.
My question is - 
Is possible to create an animation with several PNG images, by displaying them one after the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can create animation with pngs,

```
let animationImagesArray : [UIImage] = [<Add images>]
imageView.animationImages = animationImagesArray
imageView.startAnimating()
```

You can also set repeat count and animation duration as well.

**Update**
To load sequence of images via loop its better you name them in a sequence some thing like this (animationImage1.png, animationImage2.png...)

```
for i in 0..<20
        {
            let name = "\(prefix)_\(i).png"
            let image = UIImage(named: name)!
            images.append(image)
        }
```

Comment: and what is the best way to add 20 PNG images?

Comment: Best way to add 20 images is rename images in a way you can loop over them I usually do like this 
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        DLog(@"Animation image %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%d.png","AnimationImage",i]);
        [array addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%d.png",name,i]]];
    }